# Function called in window.onload does not recognize element

Tags: javascript, html, onload, getelementbyid

I am a bit confused here. I thought that the function specified in `window.onload` did not execute before the page was loaded. Nervertheless, I get an error in the below code (heres the [jsfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/raktx/)):

```
<script>
    function updateImage(url){     
        document.getElementById("foo").src = url;
    }    
    window.onload = updateImage("http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=qux");
</script>

<img id="foo" alt="" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=bar" />
```

It gives me:

```
Error: document.getElementById("foo") is null
```

When moving the image above the script all works well.

Comment: you could call it after the id, or use a dom ready function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`window.onload` expects to be a function - which it will call when the page is loaded. But what you've assigned to it is not a function. You assigned

```
updateImage("http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=qux");
```

which immediately executes the `updateImage` function, and since you don't have a `return` statement in the body of `updateImage`, the return value is `undefined`. Therefore, at the end, `window.onload` has the value `undefined`.

A solution would be to change that bit of code to:

```
window.onload = function(){
    updateImage("http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=qux");
}
```

This will cause it to call the function when the window has been loaded and do what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code.

```
window.onload = updateImage("...");
```

You are not assigning a function handler to the window onload. You are assigning the **RESULT** of the *updateImage* function. Which is executed immediately before image is loaded or even added to the DOM. To assign function handler you need:

```
window.onload = updateImage;
```

or

```
window.onload = function(){
  updateImage("http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=qux");
}
```

or by using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  updateImage("http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=qux"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger that will check is element loaded.

```
<script>

    function updateImage(url){     
        document.getElementById("foo").src = url;
    }

    function initOnLoad(sElementName) {
        var oElement = (sElementName == "body") ? document[sElementName] : document.getElementById(sElementName); 
        if(oElement != null && typeof(oElement) != "undefined") { 
            updateImage("http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=qux");
        } 
        else { 
            setTimeout(function() { 
                initOnLoad(sElementName); 
            }, 0); 
        } 
    }

    initOnLoad('body');
</script>

<img id="foo" alt="" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=bar" />
```